# return boolean based on boolean property of an object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

So I have this Boolean method that returns it's result based on boolean properties of two objects.

I pass in two objects which represent the state of a business branch. One state is the state of the branch before the storm, and the other state is after the storm.

Some of the branches may have had a rebuilding fund in place before the storm, some didn't.  So this checks for that.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    public override bool SendUpdateNotifcation(AsianBranch beforeStorm, AsianBranch afterStorm)
    {
        return beforeStorm.HasRebuildingFund && afterStorm.HasRebuildingFund;
    }
```

The property, HasRebuildindFund, is a boolean.

The problem is, that this method always returns true and it doesn't matter if both states are true, false, or ones is true and the other false.

Is my logic totally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is somewhere else 100%

Answer (score 5):

> The problem is, that this method always returns true and it doesn't matter if both states are true, false, or ones is true and the other false.

That is impossible, you're reading the situation wrong. Use a debugger and actually look at the right properties and you'll see that such a simple operation as AND always works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Deleting before I get any more downvotes. Sheesh.

Comment: btw I did use a debugger.  That's how I saw that the properties going in were true or false.  Thanks.